# Two Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, random

How can I print this?

```
1 2 3 4    
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I have this so far:

```
int ROWS = 4;
int COLS = 4;
int[][] a2 = new int[ROWS][COLS];

String output = "";   // Accumulate text here (should be StringBuilder).
//... Print array in rectangular form using nested for loops.
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
output += " " + a2[row][col];
}
output += "\n";
System.out.print(output);
```

But it just prints this:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

Also I want to print out the numbers at random.
How can I do that?

Comment: The line ROWS++; shouldn't be there.

Comment: You can edit your post to remove it. There's an "edit" link right under the tags.

Comment: You are getting zero, as not filling values in the a2 array ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to populate `a2` if you expect it to contain non-zero values:

```
for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
    a2[row][col] = row * COLS + col + 1; // <---- added this line
    output += " " + a2[row][col];
}
```

Additionally:

1. You're missing a closing curly bracket. It should go after `output += "\n";`.
2. The purpose of `ROWS++` in unclear and it looks **very** odd.

> Also I want to print out the numbers at random. How can I do that?

Three easy steps:

1. populate `a2` as above;
2. [randomly shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) `a2`;
3. print it out (you already know how to do that).

Comment: Good answer! Not fixing the whole code (since its homework) but pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use line, proposed by **aix** above: `a2[row][col] = row * COLS + col + 1;`
2. remove line `ROWS++`
3. For random numbers use `Collections.shuffle` on 1D array, and then group bu rows and columns

Answer (score 0):

well you're arrays are empty

try a direct initialization:

```
int[][] a2 = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
```

also certain errors in Code: try this:

```
int ROWS = 4;
int COLS = 4;
int[][] a2 = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};

String output = "";   // Accumulate text here (should be StringBuilder).
//... Print array in rectangular form using nested for loops.
for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) 
{
    for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) 
    {
    output += " " + a2[row][col];
    }
    output += "\n";
}
System.out.print(output);
```

Comment: Try not to fix everything when it's homework, rather point in the right direction or give hints and tips.

Answer (score 0):

To get result according  to your expectations....
firstly you have to set value of your array...

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

You get this because the default value of int is `0` thats why is showing all `0`..
To get random value of your array use `Collections.shuffle`